# Implementing Trigger on updating a column in the table in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have table named as history and the table structure is given below

```
id    dubID   country     state      city          total
 1     1       India      Delhi      Delhi           5
 2     1       India      Karnatka   Banglore        100
```

I have to do the updation in other table if `total` from any tuple becomes 100 (From  history table)

Please provide your suggestion if it is possible using triggers

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its Possible with triggers Here are the points following which you can create a trigger for your purpose..

```
1.Create trigger <trigger Name> AFTER UPDATE ON history FOR EACH ROW
2.Begin
3.Check if new.total>=100 if not then jump to 5
4.Update your desired table with proper commands
5.END IF
6.END
```

Hope that is what you want and it helps..
Good luck